# PostgreSQL installation as a user on Cygwin

Tags: database, postgresql, cygwin, database-connection, database-server

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL on Cygwin as a user following the instructions given in the cygwin package installation:

```
cygrunsrv -S cygserver
initdb -D /usr/share/postgresql/data
pg_ctl start -D /usr/share/postgresql/data -l /var/log/postgresql.log
createdb
psql
```

After I do the third step, I get the following output in the terminal,

```
$ postgres -D /usr/share/postgresql/data
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-04-12 19:04:33 PDT
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

After that, I'm unsure on what to do since I never see the command line again(the "$" sign). I'm a complete beginner when it comes to databases, so are there any 'for dummies' pointers for me?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pg_ctl -D /usr/share/postgresql/data -l /path/to/write/log/to start` if you want the server to start up and background its self.

I strongly recommend reading the PostgreSQL tutorial and manual, which cover this in detail.